# subsetting dataframe based on column names using the ":" (example: subset column B and column D until F)

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, subset

I have a wide data.table with many columns (50+)

A simplified example (with 5 columns):

```
dt <- data.table(A = 1:10, B = 1, C = 1, D = 1, E = 1, F = 1, G = 1)
```

Now I want to **subset column B and column D until F**.

In case I only wanted D until F, I could do as such:

```
dt[, D:F]
```

However, I would like to keep column B. I could achieve my desired result the long way, but this is what I'm trying to avoid:

```
dt[, c("B", "D", "E", "F")]
```

My question is whether it is possible to use a syntax as follows, which obviously doesn't work:

```
dt[, c("B", D:F)]
```

Please keep in mind that this is a simplified example and "not selecting A, C, G" wouldn't really solve my issue.

I've been wondering about this problem. I realise I can always solve it the long way but I would like to know if there's a quick way as I encounter the problem quite often.

Many thanks for any replies!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is:

```
dt[, c(.(A), .SD), .SDcols=D:F]
```

Or using `mget` together with `.SDcols`

```
dt[, c(mget(c("A", "C")), .SD), .SDcols=E:G]
```

Comment: I like the way you used `.SDcols`

Answer (score 5):

In *base* you can use `subset` to select column B and D:F.

```
subset(x, select = c(B, D:F))
#   B D E F
#1  1 1 1 1
#2  1 1 1 1
#3  1 1 1 1
#4  1 1 1 1
#5  1 1 1 1
#6  1 1 1 1
#7  1 1 1 1
#8  1 1 1 1
#9  1 1 1 1
#10 1 1 1 1
```

This will also work with `data.table`, where `cbind` could also be used like:

```
cbind(dt[,"B"], dt[, D:F])
```

Or you can use `match`:

```
i  <- match(c("B", "D", "F"), colnames(x))
x[,c(i[1],i[2]:i[3])]
```

Data:

```
x <- data.frame(A = 1:10, B = 1, C = 1, D = 1, E = 1, F = 1, G = 1)

library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x)
```

Answer (score 3):

We can make use of `select` from `dplyr` which does this easily

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)      
dt %>% 
   select(B, D:F)
#    B D E F
# 1: 1 1 1 1
# 2: 1 1 1 1
# 3: 1 1 1 1
# 4: 1 1 1 1
# 5: 1 1 1 1
# 6: 1 1 1 1
# 7: 1 1 1 1
# 8: 1 1 1 1
# 9: 1 1 1 1
#10: 1 1 1 1
```

Or use that within `[]`

```
dt[, select(.SD, B, D:F)]
```

Answer (score 3):

There has to be a better solution in pure `data.table`, but anyways:
This works (kind of)

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(A = 1:10, B = 1, C = 1, D = 1, E = 1, F = 1, G = 1)
ind <- c("B", LETTERS[4:6])
dt[, ..ind]

     B D E F
  1: 1 1 1 1
  2: 1 1 1 1
  3: 1 1 1 1
  4: 1 1 1 1
  5: 1 1 1 1
  6: 1 1 1 1
  7: 1 1 1 1
  8: 1 1 1 1
  9: 1 1 1 1
 10: 1 1 1 1
```